# Move Laravel plugin out of vendor directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, package, vendor

i have installed a Laravel forum plugin, but i have made some changes to fulfill my needs, so i need to move the whole package, which is now in the "vendor" directory out of there.

What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: Depending on your changes you needed, you probably should not have touched the base repo, but rather extended the base classes to make your changes. At this point you're probably better off forking the repo, adding in your changes, then using composer to pull yours instead of the base repo.

Comment: Thanks @Samsquanch. How should i fork the repository ?

Answer (score 1):

This article has helped me to resolve my issue:

http://laraveldaily.com/how-to-create-a-laravel-5-package-in-10-easy-steps/

i have moved the package in folder called app/Libraries/forum and there i have made the changes and then i have loaded the moved package via main composer.json and PSR-4